# Как прочитать загруженный файл csv на heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

Загружаю файл на heroku - прочитать не могу. Где сохраняется файл при загрузке POST c формы?
Прочитала, что есть папка tmp. Как прочитать?

```
 def index():
     if request.method == "POST":
            t = 0
            file = request.files["file"]
            if bool(file.filename):
                file_bytes = file.read(MAX_FILE_SIZE)
                args["file_size_error"] = len(file_bytes) == MAX_FILE_SIZE
                args["method"] = "POST"   
            try:
                    t1 = file.filename
                    t2 = "tmp/"
                    t3 = t1 + t2
                    dataset = pd.read_csv(t3)
                    t=0
            except IOError as e:
                    t = file.filename

            else:
                    t = 1
            args["t"]  = t

        return render_template("main.html", args=args)
```

---

```
<body>
    {% if args["method"] == "POST" %}
        {% if args["file_size_error"] %}
            <h1>Размер файла превышает 1мб.!</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Файл успешно загружен.</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result" align="center">

        <br> <p style="font-size:50px">Week predict:</p>
        <p style="font-size:50px">{{ args }}</p>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: читала - не понятно как в коде сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":
        t = 0
        file = request.files["file"]
        str_file_value = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        file_t = str_file_value.splitlines()
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file_t, delimiter=',')
        file_data = [row for row in csv_reader][1:]
        dataset = pd.DataFrame(file_data)
        if bool(file.filename):
            file_bytes = file.read(MAX_FILE_SIZE)
            args["file_size_error"] = len(file_bytes) == MAX_FILE_SIZE
            args["method"] = "POST"
            args["t"] = prediction(dataset)
```

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35%;
}

.result {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Predicts</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if args["method"] == "POST" %}
        {% if args["file_size_error"] %}
            <h1>Размер файла превышает 1мб.!</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Файл успешно загружен.</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result" align="center">

        <br> <p style="font-size:50px">Week predict:</p>
        <p style="font-size:50px">{{ args["t"]  }}</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```